# Vue onEnable/onDisable event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuejs3

In my vue application I need to observe an element getting enabled/disabled (It binds to a function) and by looking that I need to trigger an onEnabled/onDisabled event which will clean up some other data nodes.

So is there a listener like @click, @enabled or something?

Eg:

`<v-checkbox :value="getValue(layout.responseNode)" @change="setValue(layout.responseNode, $event)" :label="expression(layout.label)" :disabled="expression(layout.enableIf)" ></v-checkbox>`

This is the code so far with me. here enableIf will be a dynamic expression from server.

Its properly working now.

Now I need to run some more expression like

`<v-checkbox :value="getValue(layout.responseNode)" @change="setValue(layout.responseNode, $event)" :label="expression(layout.label)" :disabled="expression(layout.enableIf)" @onDisabled="expression(layout.disableCommand)" ></v-checkbox>` 
Is there an event matching onDisabled?

Comment: Can you provide more information on what you are enabling/disabling?

Comment: I modified the question a bit. Hope its clear. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend [watchers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html) you can bind a variable/computed to `:disabled` of the `checkbox` and watch the value changing

exp.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ checkboxState }}</p>
    <input type="checkbox" :disabled="checkboxState" />
    <button @click="checkboxChanged()">Disable Checkbox!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data: () => {
    return {
      checkboxState: true,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    checkboxChanged() {
      this.checkboxState = !this.checkboxState;
    },
  },
  watch: {
    checkboxState() {
      // this is fired when the checkboxState changes
      console.log("fired when checkboxState changes");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

> note: the function name and the variable must have the same name for watchers to work.

Like this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-currying-wlqn11?file=/src/App.vue:320-335)